# Google Maps Remove Markers Working Too Efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to update markers in realtime via the **refreshDiv()** function, and I have managed to workout how to add a marker + remove all markers via **addMarker()** and **clearMarkers()**. But when calling the **clearMarkers()** it clears them altogether.

Is there a way to set location of marker then move it to next location.

**Further explanation**

Im working on a project that needs to show location of of each marker, to do this I need to update the location of the marker, when update the location of a marker it leaves previous behind, so I use clearMarkers(), but this removes all markers. I need it to remove previous markers but leave the most recent there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Remove Markers</title>
        <style>

          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }

          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body onload='refreshDiv()'>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
    <script>


      var map;
      var markers = [];

    **//this is were the problem lies**

        function refreshDiv()
        {
         addMarker(37.769,-122.446);
         var refresher = setTimeout('refreshDiv()', 3000);
         clearMarkers();
        }

      function initMap() {
        var haightAshbury = {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: haightAshbury,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.


        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        addMarker(haightAshbury);
      }

       // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

      // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
      function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
      }

      // Shows any markers currently in the array.
      function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
      }

      // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
      function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
      }

    </script>
      <script async defer
        src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVQaENEYHY2g-mRhD6_tj1cSK8DhQoqHI&callback=initMap'>
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Slightly confused by your question. You want to clear all markers with a click, but set another location right after? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I working on a project that needs to show location of of each marker, to do this I need to update the location of the marker, when update the location of a marker it leaves previous behind, so I use clearMarkers(), but this removes all markers.

Comment: The problem is with `setMapOnAll()` function. When you clear markers, everything is getting to `NULL`, you need to track the latest position by the ID and have an IF-statement to check for that ID in `setMapOnAll()`. Theoretically, that would solve the issue. I will check on my end.

Comment: Thanks @cosmoonot this is driving me crazy. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did it work? You should accept both the answers below so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was clearing the markers after setting the final position, hence you couldn't see the final marker. Moving your `clearMarkers()` as the first call in `refreshDiv` fixes the issue. Have a look at the code below:.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Remove Markers</title>
        <style>

          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }

          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body onload='refreshDiv()'>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
    <script>


      var map;
      var markers = [];

  //this is were the problem lies**

        function refreshDiv()
        {
         clearMarkers();
         var position = new google.maps.LatLng(37.769,-122.446);
         addMarker(position);
         var refresher = setTimeout('refreshDiv()', 3000);
         
        }

      function initMap() {
        //var haightAshbury = {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446};
        var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(37.769, -122.446);    

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: haightAshbury,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
         
        // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.


        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        addMarker(haightAshbury);
      }

       // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

      // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
      function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
      }

      // Shows any markers currently in the array.
      function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
      }

      // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
      function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
      }

    </script>
      <script async defer
        src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVQaENEYHY2g-mRhD6_tj1cSK8DhQoqHI&callback=initMap'>
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

im a bit confused but as far as i can see you need to clear the markers first and then add the new marker

```
    function refreshDiv()
    {
     clearMarkers();
     addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(37.769, -122.446));
     setMapOnAll(map)
     var refresher = setTimeout('refreshDiv()', 3000);

    }
```

Comment: compare your code with mine, yours calls `clearMarkers()` at the end, so its obvious it will delete all markers

Comment: I thought that was it but when changing  addMarker() location it stays the same. Although  addMarker(x,y);
     setMapOnAll(map)

    x++;
    y++;